# Limpiar variable al volver a entrar al for c++

Tags: c++

Buenas , ¿Como limpiar las variables de hora, minutos, y segundos al finalizar el `for` para que me inicie en `0` ? gracias dejo mi código

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio2.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
main () {
 system ("COLOR E9");
 cout<<("\t\t\t\tPrograma reloj\n\n");
 int hr=0,min=0,seg=0;
 int hora=0,minu=0,segu=0;
 cout<<("Marque el numero para la hora\n\n:");
 cin>>hora;
 cout<<("Marque el numero para el minuto\n\n:");
 cin>>minu;
 cout<<("Marque el numero para el segundo\n\n:");
 cin>>segu;
 for ( hr=hora ; hr<12 ; hr++){
        for ( min=minu ; min<60 ; min++){
              for ( seg=segu; seg<60; seg++){
                     for ( int mls=0 ; mls<1100 ; mls++){
                     gotoxy (35,7);
                     cout << hr <<" : " << min <<" : "<< seg <<endl;
                     }
              }
        }
 }

 getch();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para que la cuenta vuelva a empezar tu código quedaría tal que así:

```
 #include<iostream>
 #include<conio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include <unistd.h>
 using namespace std;

 int main ()
 {
     system ("COLOR E9");
     cout<<("\t\t\t\tPrograma reloj\n\n");
     int hr=0,min=0,seg=0;
     int hora=0,minu=0,segu=0;

     cout<<("Marque el numero para la hora: ");
     cin>>hora;
     cout<<("\nMarque el numero para el minuto: ");
     cin>>minu;
     cout<<("\nMarque el numero para el segundo: ");
     cin>>segu;

 for ( hr=hora ; hr<=12 ; hr++)
 {
    hora=0;
     for ( min=minu ; min<60 ; min++)
     {
        minu=0;
          for ( seg=segu; seg<=60; seg++)
          {
            gotoxy(35,7);
            system("cls");
            cout << hr <<" : " << min <<" : "<< seg <<endl;
            sleep(1);
            segu=0;
      }
  }
 }
    getch();
 }
```

He añadido el system("cls"); para limpiar la pantalla de la consola tras cada segundo, además de un sleep(); con el que el programa espera 1 segundo para continuar con su proceso, ahorrando así el bucle de mili segundos que tenías.

Comment: ya lo probe y nada se me resetea el reloj y queda la parte de horas y minutos en 0 y el segundero queda en 156 y no se muebe

Answer (score 1):

Solo debes resetear a 0 después de cada ciclo su variable de control para el contador, así:

```
system("COLOR E9");
cout << ("\t\t\t\tPrograma reloj\n\n");
int hr = 0, min = 0, seg = 0;
int hora = 0, minu = 0, segu = 0;
cout << ("Marque el numero para la hora\n\n:");
cin >> hora;
cout << ("Marque el numero para el minuto\n\n:");
cin >> minu;
cout << ("Marque el numero para el segundo\n\n:");
cin >> segu;
for (hr = hora; hr<12; hr++){
    for (min = minu; min<60; min++){
        for (seg = segu; seg<60; seg++){
            for (int mls = 0; mls<1100; mls++){

                cout << hr << " : " << min << " : " << seg << endl;
            }
        }
        segu = 0;

    }
    minu = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Así mi amigo**, *si tienes alguna duda me comentas*

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio2.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
main () {
    system ("COLOR E9");
    cout<<("\t\t\t\tPrograma reloj\n\n");
    int hr=0,min=0,seg=0;
    int hora=0,minu=0,segu=0;
    cout<<("Marque el numero para la hora\n\n:");
    cin>>hora;
    cout<<("Marque el numero para el minuto\n\n:");
    cin>>minu;
    cout<<("Marque el numero para el segundo\n\n:");
    cin>>segu;
    for ( hr=hora ; hr<12 ; hr++){
        for ( min=minu ; min<60 ; min++){
            for ( seg=segu; seg<60; seg++){
                for ( int mls=0 ; mls<1100 ; mls++){
                    gotoxy (35,7);
                    cout << hr <<" : " << min <<" : "<< seg <<endl;
                }
                segu = 0;
            }
            minu = 0;
        }
        hora = 0;
    }

    getch();
}
```